# How do I use Automator to create an app or write a script which restores the custom icon of Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, icons, automator

I use a custom icon for Google Chrome, as I do with many of the other apps on my MacBook. My issue is specific to Chrome, where randomly but certainly the custom icon disappears and is replaced with a folder icon instead. I've been manually replacing it each time, but it's becoming tedious. So I would like to create a script which automatically replaces it at random intervals or an Automator app to make it all happen in one click.

My solution thus far has been:
Quit Chrome -> "Get Info" for Chrome -> Navigate to the folder where I keep my custom icons -> Click and drag the icon to the folder icon to replace it

Comment: What happens if you just lock the (invisible) custom icon file in the app package?

Comment: Tried that solution, no luck unfortunately